# New email how remove users of the From field

Tags: sharepoint-server, web, person-or-group

I am new to Sharepoint, I have a page where the users send email. They can choose the user in the `FROM:` field, along with other options too.

How can I remove a specific user of the FROM list of users ?

I remove from all the lists of users permissions in the config os the site, but the users is still appearing in the `From` list.

Comment: what is the source of your data to your "FROM" field ?

Answer (score 1):

Please share more information to further troubleshoot the issue:

You said "i have a page where the users send email", How did you send email to the page?

Do you mean when send email, there already has users in from address and you want remove the users?

Comment: I now discover the source list when editing the page and solved, i was looking for user lists so i never find